# Can "hand in hand", "face to face", "miles and miles", "coast to coast" be considered "irreversible binomials"?

Tags: terminology

> IRREVERSIBLE BINOMIALS - [Irreversible binomial is a linguistic term coined by Yakov Malkiel](http://www.omniglot.com/blog/?p=666)  in a 1959 article in the linguistics journal, Lingua, and refers to pairs of words on either side of a conjunction such as *and* that are always used in a particular order. For example, bread and butter, salt and vinegar, fish and chips, meat and potatoes, gin and tonic, time and tide, cloak and dagger, ladies and gentlemen, knife and fork, and head over heels.
>
> A noun phrase consisting of two nouns joined by a conjunction, in which the conventional order is fixed. Examples include bread and butter and kith and kin. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/irreversible-binomial

Some so called "irreversible binomials", however, use the same word twice.

> - hand in hand
> - arm in arm
> - face to face
> - cheek to cheek
> - louder and louder
> - lower and lower
> - on and on
> - round and round
> - miles and miles
> - over and over

I've gone through a few [lists](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/Binomial-term.htm) of [irreversible binomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siamese_twins_(linguistics)) where this kind is included. To me it makes no sense to call them "irreversible". Does it?  Are they?

Comment: Well, I put the term *irreversible* in an answer post somehwere here as a bit of a gentle tongue in cheek joke. They're irreversible to the extent that you can't put the wrong one first! and if you reversed them no-one would know and many people would claim you hadn't. They could be seen as part of the same group. People have studied what factors affect the order of binominals, and if the two words *weren't* the same, then arguably we would be able to predict which would come first and which second if they did indeed become frozen into an 'idiomatic' chunk.

Comment: Do we have an authoritative source for the Malkiel attribution? I'd like to use it if there is one that you know of.

Comment: They're not the same thing as the frozen forms that Malkiel called irreversible. These are basically repetitive reduplication; _again and again_ or _bigger and bigger_ are prototypical. They refer to repetitive action, augmentation, decrementing, etc. The ones Malkiel was talking about are covered in [Cooper and Ross's "World Order"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/worldorder.pdf), where they're called "freezes".

Comment: Usually such things are called idioms and idioms are fixed. I doubt that "irreversible binominals" is very helpful. In the end you need three special dictionaries if you want to understand simple grammar things: a dictionary of grammar terms, one of linguistic terms and one of mathematical terms. Grammar should be simple und not a lifelong study.

Comment: Here's a reversible irreversible: in my dialect (North London) there is a dish called "egg and chips" (which is what is says it is: a fried egg with chips). In Willy Russell's play _Shirley Valentine_, she invariably calls the dish _chips and egg_, which sounds wrong to my ears. I believe this is a feature of Liverpool dialect, rather than an idiosyncracy of the character.

Comment: An example using a verb instead of a conjunction, from [Master Mind of Mars](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks01/0100201.txt), quote: "I notice," I remarked, "that the people repeated the same phrase before this figure that they did at the last--Tur is Tur." / "Oh, no," exclaimed Dar Tarus. "On the contrary they said just exactly the opposite from what they said at the other. At that they said, Tur is Tur; while at this they absolutely reversed it and said, Tur is Tur. Do you not see? They turned it right around backwards, which makes a very great difference." Unquote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Irreversible binomials are defined as consisting of *constituent A* and *constituent B*

> a subclass of coordinate constructions, viz. the coordination of *two single words which belong to the same form class*; examples would be hard and fast, or salt and pepper.

Per Arne Lohman's paper, [A processing view on order in reversible and
irreversible binomials](http://anglistik.univie.ac.at/fileadmin/user_upload/dep_anglist/weitere_Uploads/Views/VIEWS_21_2012__Lohmann.pdf) (2012), the reason irreversible binomials take that form reflects syntactical reasons, e.g. where there exists *selection pressure*:

> A certain order in extra-linguistic reality has been found to be reflected in the order of constituents (see Malkiel 1959, Benor & Levy 2006). This refers mostly to temporal order, e.g. birth and death, but may also refer to other scales, e.g. eighth and ninth.

A conjunction like *less and less*, in which there is no selection pressure, and which does not consist of two *different* words ordered in the same manner each time, does not meet the standard for an *irreversible binomial*. While all irreversible binomials are lexicalized units, not all lexicalized units are irreversible binomials.

I would say that binomials (if they are called that in linguistics) of the *less and less* and *more and more* types are a different kind of lexicalized unit.

Answer (score 0):

> I've gone through a few lists of irreversible binomials where this
>   kind is included.

People are stupid.

> To me it makes no sense to call them "irreversible".

You are correct.

> Does it?

It makes no sense to call them irreversible binomials.

> Are they?

Never and never.