# Compound words/phrases that still make sense when their order is swapped

Tags: idiom-requests, compound-words, list-request

Thinking of compound words or phrases where the order of the words can be swapped around and still make sense:

Examples: 
 Lighthouse - House Light 
Birdhouse - House Bird
Racetrack - Track Race

So far that's all I've been able to discover. Is there a word for this reversibility phenomenon?

Comment: Please note that suggestions for other examples turns this into a list question, which is not allowed. Asking whether there is a term for the phenomenon is reasonable.

Comment: Your question seems to have an answer [**here**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/198745/can-hand-in-hand-face-to-face-miles-and-miles-coast-to-coast-be-consi?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C120.0778)

Comment: A fool's errand as none of those actually work.

Comment: And I don't think changing the order does not change the meaning.

Comment: @Cent I don't think OP means that the meaning stays the same; just that the words still have _some unspecified_ meaning after the swap.

Answer (score 1):

A basic phrase that will get you results is *reversible compound words*. For instance, [a Notes and Queries submission to *The Guardian*](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-11025,00.html) asks for *reversible compound words* like houseboat/boathouse:

> 'Houseboat' is an English compound noun in which the two elements can be reversed to give another English compound noun, 'boathouse'. Are there any other genuine reversible compound nouns such as this?

This sort of thing may be popular with word puzzlers, but there isn't a standardized term of art. [NPR's Puzzler](https://www.npr.org/2023/03/05/1161192410/sunday-puzzle-in-reverse) called these *reversible words*. In a [1970 issue of a periodical called *Word Ways*](https://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol3/iss1/13/), letter writer Faith Eckler complains about author David Silverman's vague definition of "word cycles," before giving several examples that fit reversible compound words, like *shotgun* and *gunshot*. Going to [the original article in 1969](https://digitalcommons.butler.edu/wordways/vol2/iss2/15/) shows Silverman's context: he's giving lots of curious words and puzzles, and "Word Cycles" (including "bi-cycles" of two elements or "tri-cycles" of three elements) seems like a nonce word for the formation. As for recent usage, Twitter handle Haggard Hawks picked up *word cycles* in [a Feb. 15, 2021 tweet](https://twitter.com/HaggardHawks/status/1361317500324044800?lang=en), while also giving the generic gloss *reversible compound word*:

> Also known as rotograms or bicycles, **WORD-CYCLES** are **reversible compound words**, the two halves of which can be placed in either order to create entirely different terms—like HOUSEWORK and WORKHOUSE, GUNSHOT and SHOTGUN, OVERTAKE and TAKEOVER, and WOODPECKER and PECKERWOOD.

So if you're talking to puzzlemasters, it's possible they'll have heard of *word cycles*. For anyone else, just use a description: *reversible compound word*.

Comment: Yes, your quoted ones work, the OPs do not.

Comment: @Lambie Do the compound nouns have to be solid? Some class, for instance, the compound noun 'inkwell', 'ink-well' and 'ink well' as mere spelling variants of the same lexical (obviously not orthographic)  word. They're certainly the same lexeme.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Solid or not, the OPs  **do not work**, except in some poetical universe.

Comment: @Lambie House light: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/house-light_n?tab=meaning_and_use#991351381 . House bird: https://www.oed.com/dictionary/house-bird_n?tab=meaning_and_use#991351105 . Only *track race* lacks an OED entry.

Comment: I can't see any of that.

Comment: I'm sure there are many things I can't see that I wouldn't pronounce non-existent.

Comment: @Lambie House light: "(a) One of the (esp. interior) lights of a house; (b) (in plural) the lights in the auditorium of a theatre, etc., which are dimmed or extinguished during a stage performance." House bird: "(a) A person who stays in or about the house; (in early use) a cowardly or unadventurous person; (later) a woman who devotes herself to domestic duties (now rare); (b) any bird that nests in or about a house or other building; (also) a domestic or pet bird."